# Ajax - doubles the content in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client, crud

I've got problem with JavaScript Ajax. I've created simple CRUD app. While I'm editing one record in table for the first time data are displayed correct, but in case of second, third, … edit data are duplicated twicely, etc.

It looks like there is some problem with this part of below code:

```
var products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

as it passes too much data. While second editing - 2 objects instead of 1, etc.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#update").hide();

assignDataToTable();

$('table').on('click', 'button[id="edit"]', function(e){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
   var name = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(2)').text(); 
   var price = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(3)').text(); 
   var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(4)').text();

    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#price").val(price);
    $("#quantity").val(quantity);

    $("#update").show();
    $("#save").hide();

    $("#update").click(function() {

        var priceNum = parseFloat($("#price").val());
        var quantityNum = parseInt($("#quantity").val());

        var jsonVar = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            price: priceNum,
            quantity: quantityNum
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:"PUT",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonVar),
            contentType: "application/json",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/api/products/" + id,
            success: function(data){
                alertUsing("Zmieniono", true);
                $("#update").hide();
                $("#save").show();
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#price").val("");
                $("#quantity").val("");
                assignDataToTable();


            },
            error: function(err) {  
                console.log(err);
            }


    });
    });

})

  function assignDataToTable() {
    $("#tbody").empty();
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url:"http://localhost:8080/api/products",
      success: function(data) {
         var products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

          console.log(products);
        for (var i in products) {
            $("#tbody").append(`<tr> 
                        <td>${products[i].id}</td> 
                        <td>${products[i].name}</td> 
                        <td>${products[i].price}</td> 
                        <td>${products[i].quantity}</td> 
                        <td>  <button id='delete' class='btn btn-danger'>Usun</button> 
                       <button id='edit' class='btn btn-warning'>Edytuj</button>  </td> 
                    </tr>`);
        }
      },
      error: function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
        }
    });

}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<title>Hurtownia</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<!-- <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Id</th>
                  <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
                  <th scope="col">Cena</th>
                  <th scope="col">Ilosc</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tbody">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="form-group form-vales">
                <input id="nameSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwa">
                <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Szukaj</button>
                <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwa">
                <input id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Cena">
                <input id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Ilosc">
                <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Dodaj</button>
                <button id="update" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edytuj</button>
                <div class="alert" role="alert">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to stringify the data returned from the server. Assuming your server is returning JSON. Your function `assignDataToTable` contains an ajax asynchronous call so it will return before the 'success`or`error` function is called. This is almost certainly not what you want. This means that user interaction could happen before your table has updated causing corruption. However, it's not necessarily causing the error you are encountering.